# Argument type List<LatLng> can't be assigned to parameter type 'LatLng'

Tags: flutter

How do I define an array of markers for Flutter as the `position` property for the `Marker` widget  does not accept a List of LatLng points. How I do solve this?

```
final List<LatLng> _markerLocations = [
    LatLng(3.082519, 101.592201),
    LatLng(3.083355, 101.589653),
    LatLng(3.08171, 101.587507),
    LatLng(3.082519, 101.592201),
  ];
```

```
void _initMarkers() async {
    Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('loop_route'),
      position: _markerLocations
    );
    setState(() {
      markers.add(_markerLocations);
    });
}
```

```
void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
  setState((){
    mapController = controller;
    _initMarkers();
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Marker` takes instance of `LatLng` because there can be only one `LatLng` for one `Marker`. One marker can be only at one position in map.

You will need to create as much markers as much `LatLng` you have.

You will have to do this:

```
_markerLocations.forEach((LatLng latLong){
    markers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId('loop_route'),
      position: latLong
    ));
  });
```

by replacing:

```
 markers.add(_markerLocations);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204334/discussion-on-answer-by-kalpesh-kundanani-argument-type-listlatlng-cant-be-as).